# Modify indexed row of table

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts2

I have one JSP page, and in this page I need to select one or more rows in one HTML table, then delete or modify the selected records.

To do this, I've developed a code that, when I click on row, I pass the index of the row.

for example:

[image: table]

for this table, if I click on Bologna, I need to modify only the row of Bologna.

But now if I click on Genova or Milano or Trieste I can always modify only the first row: why?

```
    function edit(x, lenght) {

    alert(x+ "/" + lenght);
    var    i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= lenght; i++) 
    {
    alert(i + "/" + x);
        if (i == x) 
        {

            var desc = document.getElementById("desc");
            var secret = document.getElementById("secret");
             row.style.backgroundColor = '#E1EEF4'; 
            desc.style.bord    er = "1px solid black";
            desc.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            desc.readOnly = false;

            secret.style.border = "1px solid black";
            secret.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            secret.readOnly = false;
        }

    }
}
```

while this is the piece of code HTML for my row:

```
<td align="center" style="width: 5px;"><img
    src="<s:url value="/images/x.png"/>" style="width: 15px;"></img></td>
<td align="center" style="width: 5px;"><img
    onclick="edit('<s:property value="%{#status.count - 1 + startUtente}" />','<s:property value="%{listaUtenti.size}" />');"
    src="<s:url value="/images/ed_propr.gif"/>"
    style="width: 15px;"></img></td>
<td align="center"><s:label name="id" value="%{id}"
        size="2" /></td>
<td align="center"><s:label name="userId" value="%{userId}"
        size="20" /></td>
<td align="center"><s:textfield id="desc"
        name="descrizione"
        style="border:0px; background-color : transparent;"
        readonly="true" value="%{descrizione}" size="30" /></td>
<td align="center"><s:textfield id="secret"
        name="daTopSecret"
        style="border:0px; background-color : transparent;"
        readonly="true" value="%{daTopSecret}" size="15" /></td>
```

Comment: the "secret" field has always the same id for every row, you need to parameterize it with the #status.count or #status.index (along with every other field )

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: `id="secret_%{#status.index}"`

Comment: ok, but after how it use this id? how can i pass it on "secret an "desc" field?

Comment: `var secret = document.getElementById("secret_" + x);` ?

Comment: why this return me null? maybe i don't have element with id "secret_" or "desc_"

Comment: look in the source code for the id of your elements. Maybe it's not been translated with `id="secret_1"` and is still `id="secret_%{#status.index}"`, in which case just use input type text instead of s:textfield and use s:property for the id

Comment: ok, perfect work perfectly!! now i need to assign the same id to my TR tag, but don't view an ID. <tr> tag, accept an id?

Comment: You're not putting any effort in this, aren't you ? Yes, it supports id

Comment: yes  but the same parameter that i pass to "desc_" or "secret_", in tr(row_) i don't see the number of index but this (#status.count - 1 + startUtente)

Comment: I've assembled the comments into an answer to help future visitors. The reason it is not translated is because <tr> is a simple HTML attribute, not a Struts tag, hence you need to inject an <s:property /> in it.

Comment: Also status.index is equal to count-1 (index is 0-based, count is 1-based)

Comment: You're welcome @skatedan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "secret" field has always the same id for every row, you need to parameterize it with the `#status.count` or `#status.index` (along with every other field ), like this

```xml
<s:textfield id="secret_%{#status.index}" />
```

then read it in the same way in Javascript:

```xml
var secret = document.getElementById("secret_" + x);
```